# Why cant i create hovering background for entire <li>?

Tags: css

For some weird reason i cant change the background of the entire list item even though i selected the list.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="project-item" ng-controller="openProjectsCtrl">
    <ol>
        <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="project in projects | orderBy:'Posted' : true">
            <h4>{{project.Title}}</h4>
            {{project.Skills}}
            <span class="col-md-6">{{project.Budget}}</span>
            <span class="col-md-6 timestamp">{{project.Posted|timeago}}</span>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

<style>
.project-item>ol>li:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Did you mean all of the list item _including the count number_?

Comment: Found out its related to the float left property on first span.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted works fine.  See this example.

```css
.project-item>ol>li:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-item" ng-controller="openProjectsCtrl">
    <ol>
        <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="project in projects | orderBy:'Posted' : true">
            <h4>{{project.Title}}</h4>
            {{project.Skills}}
            <span class="col-md-6">{{project.Budget}}</span>
            <span class="col-md-6 timestamp">{{project.Posted|timeago}}</span>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems  to work.
Change the colors its pretty hard to see a gray color on a white background.

```css
.project-item ol li:hover {

  background-color: firebrick;

}
```

```html
<div class="project-item" ng-controller="openProjectsCtrl">
  <ol>
    <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="project in projects | orderBy:'Posted' : true">
      <h4>{{project.Title}}</h4>
      {{project.Skills}}
      <span class="col-md-6">{{project.Budget}}</span>
      <span class="col-md-6 timestamp">{{project.Posted|timeago}}</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes the code works outside of my app. But inside it does not include both spans in hover.

Comment: @Elevant:  What browser are you using?  Chrome includes both spans in the background color.